# Select in complex dataset query

Tags: dataset, filtering

I want to use Select for a more complex dataset query. Part of the query shall be dynamic, depending on the user input. The Select part looks something like

```
Select[
 #Group == cGroup
   && #"Component Type" == component2
   && NumberQ@#[xaxisElement]
   && NumberQ@#[yaxisElement]
   && (#Reference == "ref1" || #Reference == "ref2" || #Reference == "ref3")
  &]
```

The last line with the references shall be dynamically produced, depending which references the user wants to be included. I found that I can produce such a list with

```
Apply[Or, Equal[Slot["Reference"], #] & /@ a]
```

where a represents the list of references that the user chose, e.g.

```
a={"refer 1","refer 2","refer 3","refer 4"}
```

However, when I include the above code in Select, it does not work; i.e.

```
Select[
 #Group == cGroup
   && #"Component Type" == component2
   && NumberQ@#[xaxisElement]
   && NumberQ@#[yaxisElement]
   && (Apply[Or, Equal[Slot["Reference"], #] & /@ a])
  &]
```

does not work. When I copy & past the output from the Apply[...] command, it works. I have no clue, why and how I can get it to work so the user generate list is part of Select.

Addition:
Here is a simplified example how the program looks like

```
data = {{"Group", "Component Type", "Reference"}, {"g1", "a", 
    "ref1"}, {"g1", "a", "ref2"}, {"g1", "b", "ref1"}, {"g1", "b", 
    "ref1"}, {"g1", "b", "ref2"}, {"g1", "a", "ref3"}, {"g2", "b", 
    "ref1"}, {"g2", "b", "ref1"}, {"g2", "a", "ref3"}, {"g3", "a", 
    "ref1"}, {"g3", "b", "ref3"}, {"g3", "d", "ref2"}};
dataset = Dataset[AssociationThread[First@data, #] & /@ Rest@data];

Query[Select[#Group == "g1" && #"Component Type" == 
      "a" && (#Reference == "ref1" || #Reference == 
        "ref2") &]]@dataset
```

Now what I would like to have is that the Reference part in the parentheses are generated depending on user input. As it is, datasets with ref1 and ref2 are displayed. But when a user choses only ref1, datasets with only ref1 should be displayed. Or, if the user chooses ref1, ref2 and ref3, all datasets with these references are displayed (plotted, to be precise).

Comment: `Reference` is a named slot of what `Association`?

Comment: Yes, it's a named slot of Association. Basically, datasets from certain references shall be selectable.

Comment: What I mean is, Slot : Association :: "Reference" : ? -- in your application.

Comment: I have a Dataset and one Column is labelled Reference (others e.g. Group, Component Type, etc.). Certain datasets from Group, Component Type, ... and Reference are chosen. References are displayed with checkboxes. The user ticks the checkboxes and only those References will be displayed in a plot. Hence, the list for the References need to be build each time.  -- If this is still confusing, I could include a simplified dataset.

Comment: That'd help b/c as-is, `Apply[...]` doesn't work as `Slot` expects an `Association`, which `a` is not.

Comment: OK, I added a simplified code and hope this helps. I realise that there is an error, I just don't know how to fix this. – And thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How's this:

```
refQuery[references_List] := 
 With[{refs = 
    references // Map[Equal[Slot["Reference"], #] &] // Apply[Or]},
  Off[Function::slot1];
  Query[Select[#Group == "g1" && #"Component Type" == "a" && refs &]]
  ]

refQuery[{"ref1", "ref3"}]@dataset

(* {<|"Group" -> "g1", "Component Type" -> "a", 
  "Reference" -> "ref1"|>, <|"Group" -> "g1", "Component Type" -> "a",
   "Reference" -> "ref3"|>} *)
```

Comment: This looks great! Thanks a lot. I don't yet fully understand your code, but that's probably the reason I couldn't find the solution myself.